# Как вывести значение, если ключа нет в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть переменная `$city` и массив:

```
$arr = array(
    [1]=>one,
    [2]=>two,
    [3]=>three
);
```

Количество элементов массива и ключей не известно и написано для примера.
Мне надо, чтобы в случае, если приходит значение в массиве задевается, к примеру, `$city=one`, выводилось строка:

```
<a href='#' class='cityGeoLink active' data-id='$key' >$value</a>
```

где `$key` – ключ массива, а его значение это `$value`.

Если не задевается, к примеру, `$city=two`:

```
<a href='#' class='cityGeoLink' data-id='$key' >$value</a>
```

А если ни одно не задевается (к примеру `$city=four`), то

```
echo "<a href='#' class='cityGeoLink' data-id='15' > $city</a></br>";
```

Я думал решить так:

```
foreach($s as $key => $value){
    switch ($city) {
        case ($city == $value):
                echo "<a href='#' class='cityGeoLink active' data-id='$key' >$value</a></br>";
                break;
        case ($city != $value):
                echo "<a href='#' class='cityGeoLink' data-id='$key' >$value</a></br>";
                break;
        default:
                echo "<a href='#' class='cityGeoLink' data-id='15' >$city</a></br>";
            } 
        }
```

Если попадаем в массив, то всё хорошо: как я уже писал `$city=one`, но если `$city=four`, то вываливаются первых три строки вида:

```
 <a href='#' class='cityGeoLink active' data-id='1' >one</a>
 <a href='#' class='cityGeoLink active' data-id='2' >two</a>
 <a href='#' class='cityGeoLink active' data-id='3' >three</a>
```

а вот

```
 <a href='#' class='cityGeoLink active' data-id='15' >four</a>
```

не получается.

Можете что-нибудь предложить?

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что в вопросе речь про города. Есть это действительно так, то поменяйте на досуге везде `sity` на `city`.

Comment: @Regent это имеет значение для ответа ? $city в другом деле используется и тоже связаном с городами.

Comment: Нет, к вопросу это отношения не имеет, только к восприятию кода.

Comment: Вам весь массив вывести нужно?

Comment: А как у вас может быть **три** варианта действий? Одна переменная может быть либо равна другой (`$city == $value`) либо не равна (`$city != $value`) третьего, увы, не дано. Ровно та же ситуация и с наличием элемента в массиве: он может либо быть там либо нет. Что-то не то вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: Странно что Вам хоть какие-то ответы дали. Вы перечитывали свой вопрос? Если приходит значение в массиве задевается -  на каком языке это предложение?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev вы правильно сказали  у меня есть масив и переменная мне надо 1 вывести все значения которые находятся в масиве и если значение в масиве равно переменой то выводимой ссылке присвоить класс active если нет то не присваивать класс актив, а  если переменой нет в масиве то вывести все значения масива + значения переменой

Comment: @Sergalas, могу только пожелать удачи и нормально сформулированных вопросов ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь можно обойтись без циклов

```
if (in_array($sity, $s))) {
   echo "<a href='#' class='sityGeoLink active' data-id='$key' >$value</a></br>";
}
else {
   echo "<a href='#' class='sityGeoLink' data-id='$key' >$value</a></br>";
}
```

Comment: вы мне оптимизировали код а не нашли ответ. Мне надо по факту три действия если значение то если не то и если вообще его нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужно использовать цикл и switch если вы хотите вывести одну ссылку, просто вам нужно пришла ли переменная `$city` и знать есть ли такое значение в массиве:

```
if(!empty($city)){
    if (($key = array_search($city, $arr))) {
        echo "<a href='#' class='sityGeoLink active' data-id='$key' >$city</a></br>";
    }else {
        echo "<a href='#' class='sityGeoLink' data-id='15' >$city</a></br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<a href='#' class='sityGeoLink' data-id='15' >Empty</a></br>";
}
```

Если вы хотите так же вывести весь массив, то в вашем примере никогда не сработает условие `default`, если `$city` пустая то всегда будет выполнятся условие `case ($city != $value):`, вам просто нужно проверить существование `$city` до или после обработки массива в зависимости от нужного места вывода

```
if(empty($city)){
    echo "<a href='#' class='sityGeoLink' data-id='15' >$city</a></br>";
}
foreach($s as $key => $value){
    $active = $city == $value ? ' active':'';
    echo "<a href='#' class='sityGeoLink".$active."' data-id='$key' >$value</a></br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте поднимемся до уровня общей задачи.

1. Если запрошенный город есть в списке, нужно вывести ссылку на город.
2. Если запрошенного города нет в списке, нужно вывести ссылку на новый город.
3. Если на входе вообще не то, то вывести ссылку на место с анализом ошибки.
   Особенность третьего случая в том, что введённые данные не обязаны быть текстом.

Возможно такое решение:

```
$arr = array(
    "1" => "one",
    "2" => "two",
    "3" => "three"
);

var_dump($arr);

function print_result($key, $city){
    if(is_null($key)){
        $text = "fault";    
    }elseif(!is_string($city)&&!is_integer($city)){
        $text = gettype($city);
    }else{
        $text = htmlspecialchars($city);
    }
    if($key){
        echo "<a href='#' class='cityGeoLink active' data-id='$key' >$text</a></br>";
    }else{
        echo "<a href='#' class='cityGeoLink' data-id='15' >$text</a></br>";
    }   
}

$test_array = array_merge($arr,array("four", "", null, 0, 123, $arr));
var_dump($test_array);
foreach($test_array as $city){
    $key = array_search($city,$arr);
    var_dump($key);
    print_result($key, $city);
}
```